# CSS Columns Without Floats: Need Parent Element's Height to be Correct

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.columns
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.column
{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

The .columns div gets a height of zero when this is rendered. How can I get it to take the height of the .column div?

What I ultimately want to do here is use top/bottom and absolute positioning to create a row of columnar content, but be able to essentially "clear" the .columns element so I can put stuff beneath it.

(I'm trying to do this without floats/clears, to allow for a fixed-fluid-fixed three column layout with the columns in the right order from left to right.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need a `<br style="clear:both;">` inside columns outside column to do this. I don't think there is another way. Also, i would remove the `bottom: 0;` which is not doing anything and could create issues.

Comment: An alternative is to make columns position absolute, which I dont think you want.

Comment: The <br> actually only gives the parent the height of the <br> tag, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your columns inline-blocks. This would allow you to place them side by side, without making them `position:absolute;`, allowing the parent to contain them.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VEAUD/1/)

While this does not use floats /  clears, it has a similiar effect to floats, so may not be what you want. However, I figured I'd point it out as you may be able to find a work around with this (not exactly sure what you want, other wise I'd try).

Also, while this is a (yuck) table hack, you can make `.columns` a `display:table;` and `.column` a `display:table-cell;`, which gives interesting results.